# SSL certificate chain is incomplete

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have reviewed all the similar questions to mine that have been asked on here but haven't found a resolution that I understand. The gist of my problem is I am getting a "This server's certificate chain is incomplete" warning when I test my SSL certificate on SSL Labs and thus, browser warnings when I try to use it.

I've read in numerous places that I need to concatenate the cert with the intermediate certificate, my problems with this are 1) I don't know where the intermediate certificate is located and 2) there is already a concatenated certificate file called "fullchain.pem" that was installed.

It looks to me like everything is in place, so I am lost.

Some background info, this is a certificate for a website on a Digital Ocean OpenLiteSpeed server. I installed the certificate using Certbot. There are no other sites on the server.

Here are the cert files I currently have installed.

/etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/README

/etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/privkey.pem

/etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/fullchain.pem

/etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/chain.pem

/etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/cert.pem

Can anyone out there help me out with this? I'd appreciate it and thank you in advance.

Comment: `fullchain.pem` already contains your certificate and the only intermediate certificate (in this order). [This tutorial](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/ssl-setup/) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache config looks like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/idd-mex.org/chain.pem
```

Have a look at your server config to insert the three files or file-paths (cert, key, chain). Maybe this [Howto](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/lets-encrypt-ssl-on-openlitespeed/) would help.

*Sidenote: the letsencrypt chain.pem includes the generated certificate and the letsencrypt CA certificate. When there is no separate option for the CA / Chain, then use chain.pem as certificate.*

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I had gone through that HowTo page several times, but just now realized that I was using the fullchain certificate rather than the cert certificate in the server configuration. Changing that has resolved the matter on all browsers except Firefox. Trying to figure that one out now...